# Different behavior due to different "looping styles"

Tags: python, file, io

I have a simple problem. Navigate to a certain line in a fine, and delete everything after that. I use the suitable file.truncate() call. However, the two snippets of code below behave differently.

1)

```
with open(file, "a+b", 1) as f:
  #Navigate to the MARKER
  while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if MARKER in line:
      f.truncate()
      f.write(stuff)
      break
```

2)

```
with open(file, "a+b", 1) as f:
  #Navigate to the MARKER
  for line in f:
    if MARKER in line:
      f.truncate()
      f.write(stuff)
      break
```

(1) behaves as expected. However in case of (2), the file in truncated several lines *after* the MARKER is found. I speculate that there is some buffering going on, but as you can see, I explicitly define the buffering behavior as "line buffered" to the open() call.

Any thoughts? I would like to use the more intuitive "for line in file" syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html), 5. Built-in Types / 5.9. File Objects:

> In order to make a for loop the most
>   efficient way of looping over the
>   lines of a file (a very common
>   operation), the next() method uses a
>   hidden read-ahead buffer.

BTW: It is generally discouraged to use keywords (e.g. `file`) as variable names.

Comment: @Fenisko The fact there's a read-ahead buffer gives no evidence concerning if **truncate()** does its job at the end of the file because the file is opened in ``'a+'`` mode or if it's done as usual at the current position attained (that is to say at the end of the chunk read after the filling of the buffer, the mode ``'a'`` doing no matter)

Comment: @eyquem - Hmm, I did not try the truncation part. Maybe I should.

Answer (score 3):

The clue seems to be in [this bit of Python's C source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7b71872fb66a/Objects/fileobject.c#l2254) -- Python 2.7 seems to use a 8 KB readahead buffer for `for line in file:`.

Comment: Very interesting link. But the fact there's a read-ahead buffer gives no evidence concerning if **truncate()** does its job at the end of the file because the file is opened in ``'a+'`` mode or if it's done as usual at the current position attained (that is to say at the end of the chunk read after the filling of the buffer, the mode ``'a'`` doing no matter)

Comment: @eyquem If you read the question again, you'll notice that the first example (both are using the `'a'` mode) using `f.readline()` truncates at the correct position , thus, there clearly is evidence. The append mode only means that **writes** go to the end of the file. `truncate()` doesn't write any data, it just changes the file size in the metadata, thus it operates on the current file position even in append mode.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a `for x in y` type of statement expects y not to change within the loop. You are breaking that contract.

Comment: @euphoria83: Out of interest, is this contract documented explicitly somewhere?

Comment: @euphoria83 - But he is also breaking from the loop immediately after the y is changed.

Comment: @euphoria83 I don't see the connection with the problem. What do you mean ?

Comment: @euphoria83 Not only it doesn't have connection, but it's false. Can you give an exemple of code in which there's a loop ``for x in y`` and **y** changes within the loop ? I think it is impossible to find one.

Comment: @eyquem **Exactly**. I think you misunderstood something. You generally **don't** find such code, that was the point. Try modifying the dictionary `d` inside `for key, value in d.iteritems():`, it will raise an error. What euphoria83 is saying is that you shouldn't change the item you're iterating over, since the behavior is usually not well defined.

Comment: @Aleksi - Thanks for putting it so well. I was trying to come up with a nice statement to explain it. But you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `'a'` mode:

> a
>
> Open for appending (writing at end
>   of file). The file is created if it
>   does not exist. **The stream is
>   positioned at the end of the file**.
>
> a+
>
> Open for reading and appending
>   (writing at end of file). The file is
>   created if it does not exist. The
>   initial file position for reading is
>   at the beginning of the file, but
>   **output is always appended to the end of the file**.
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

.

### EDIT

My above answer is wrong.

I already knew that looping over the lines of a file uses a read-ahead of buffer, but I believed that **truncate()** would trigger the file's pointer to be moved to the end of the file, since, as far as I know, truncating a file consists in writing a little sequence of bytes called EOF meaning end-of-file, and `'a'` mode always provoke writing at the end of a file  whatever is the position of the file's pointer just before the moment of writing.

Well, it's not like that, I should have verified by executing a code. So my answer deserves a downvote.

But downvoting without any explanation is shabby and frustrating in such a case in which the error in this answer isn't evident.

.

The following code shows that the file's pointer isn't moved to the end of the file before the action of **truncate()**.

To clear things, the file 'fileA' is composed of lines having each a length of 100 characters ( '\r\n comprised), ending like that ('\r\n' are not visible here):

```
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000100
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000200
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000300
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000400
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000500
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000600
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000700
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000800
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00000900
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00001000
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00001100
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00001200
....ffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00001300
............................
```

The code:

```
print '\n===================== 1 ==================\n'

from os.path import getsize

# length of ecr is 90 :
ecr = 10*'a' + 10*'b' + 10*'c' + 10*'d' + 10*'e' +\
      10*'f' + 10*'g' + 10*'h' + 10*'i'


# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # Length of each written line is 100 :
        # 90 (ecr) + 8 (str(i).zfill(8)) + 2 ('\r\n')
        # File's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
# truncating file at uncontroled position
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00000800' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # in the file if there wasn't a reading buffer
            g.truncate()
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
```

result

```
===================== 1 ==================

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00000800\r\n'   g.tell()== 8192
size of fileA after truncating :  8192
```

.

So, AKX and Fenisko are right when evoking the buffer (however they didn't test this hypothesis more than me) because the opening of the file in `'a'` mode have no influence on the action of **truncate()**. I think it is what the upper cased sentence in the following extract of the doc says:

> file.truncate([size]) Truncate the
>   file’s size. If the optional size
>   argument is present, the file is
>   truncated to (at most) that size. The
>   size defaults to the current position.
>   THE CURRENT FILE POSITION IS NOT
>   CHANGED
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate

Until now, I had never understood this sentence.

.

As pointed out by AKX, the size of the buffer is **8192** .... for the first reading.

But for the next readings, the buffer is manifestly **10240** characters long:

```
print '\n=================== 2 ====================\n'

from os.path import getsize

# length of ecr is 90 :
ecr = 10*'a' + 10*'b' + 10*'c' + 10*'d' + 10*'e' +\
      10*'f' + 10*'g' + 10*'h' + 10*'i'


# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # length of each written line is 100
        # file's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
# truncating file at uncontroled position
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00008100' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # in the file if there wasn't a reading buffer
            g.truncate()
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')

# -----------

print
# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # length of each written line is 100
        # file's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
# truncating file at uncontroled position
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00008200' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # in the file if there wasn't a reading buffer
            g.truncate()
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')

# -----------

print
# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # length of each written line is 100
        # file's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
# truncating file at uncontroled position
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00018400' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # in the file if there wasn't a reading buffer
            g.truncate()
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')

# -----------

print
# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # length of each written line is 100
        # file's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
# truncating file at uncontroled position
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00018500' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # in the file if there wasn't a reading buffer
            g.truncate()
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
```

result

```
=================== 2 ====================

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00008100\r\n'   g.tell()== 8192
size of fileA after truncating :  8192

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00008200\r\n'   g.tell()== 18432
size of fileA after truncating :  18432

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00018400\r\n'   g.tell()== 18432
size of fileA after truncating :  18432

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00018500\r\n'   g.tell()== 28672
size of fileA after truncating :  28672
```

.

By the way, **truncate()** doesn't close the file:

```
print '\n=================== 3 ====================\n'

from os.path import getsize

# length of ecr is 90 :
ecr = 10*'a' + 10*'b' + 10*'c' + 10*'d' + 10*'e' +\
      10*'f' + 10*'g' + 10*'h' + 10*'i'


# creation of a file whose length exceeds the reading buffer's size
with open('fileA.txt','wb') as f:
    for i in xrange(100,53001,100): # 530 turns of iteration
        f.write(ecr + str(i).zfill(8) + '\r\n')
        # length of each written line is 100
        # file's length will be 53000


print 'size of fileA before truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
with open('fileA.txt','a+b') as g:
    for line in g:
        if '00000200' in line:
            print repr(line[78:]),'  g.tell()==',g.tell()
            # at this point, 800 characters should have been read
            # if there wasn't a buffer
            g.truncate()
    g.seek(6000,0)
    k = 0
    for li in g:
        k+=1
        print 'k==',k,'   ',repr(li[-32:])
        if k==7:
            break
print 'size of fileA after truncating : ',getsize('fileA.txt')
```

result

```
=================== 3 ====================

size of fileA before truncating :  53000
'hhiiiiiiiiii00000200\r\n'   g.tell()== 8192
k== 1     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006100\r\n'
k== 2     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006200\r\n'
k== 3     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006300\r\n'
k== 4     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006400\r\n'
k== 5     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006500\r\n'
k== 6     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006600\r\n'
k== 7     'gghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiii00006700\r\n'
size of fileA after truncating :  8192
```

But if a writing instruction is placed just after **truncate()**, the behavior of the program becomes incoherent. Try it.

Comment: You are mistaken about `truncate()` and `EOF`. Truncating a file only changes the file size in the file metadata (and frees the space for other use). There is no "sequence of bytes for EOF". If there was, we would see files getting accidentally/randomly truncated because the file data just happened to contain the magic sequence. File size is saved in the metadata, and `EOF` is just a notification that some libraries give to the user when they notice that they have read all the file data up to the file size.

Comment: @Akeski Torhamo Thank you for this explanation. That was an idea born of insufficient readings on the subject. So you mean that when the operating system is reading a file , it constantly updates a counter to know if the file's pointer is still in the file or has reached the end ? That surprises me a little. I thought that it was constantly verifying on each character read that it wasn't the (hence inexisting) EOF signal. But what you explain is more coherent with the functionning of the control of the files by an OS , based on a File Allocation Table. Thank you

Comment: @Akeski Torhamo Oh in fact, I rather  think that the OS reads and move the file's pointer after having calculated the number of characters it can read or move, taking account of the current position of the pointer and of the length of the file.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Actually, python (or the c library) maintains another file pointer internally, separate from the operating system one, since `fileobj.readline()` would be **really** inefficient othewise, since it'd have to make a system call for every character. `fileobj.tell()` returns the python file pointer (that you are, and should be using), but you can see the "raw" one by using low-level file operations: `os.lseek(fileobj.fileno(), 0, 1)`. It follows that mixing low-level and high-level file operations is obvisouly not a very good idea. :)